# Get most recent posts from specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    ?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post); ?> 
    <div>
        <?php the_date(); ?>
        <br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>   
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am trying to get the 10 most recent posts from a category named 'Webinar'. How can this be done? At the moment the code above works in showing 10 posts but not specific from the webinar category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This list of arguments is what drives the data that is fetched from the database:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title' );
```

You ask for 10 posts, ordered by title in an ascending order. It seems you simply forgot to include the category in your search conditions. Try:

```
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 10, 'order'=> 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'title', 'category' => 'Webinar');
```

Comment: Yikes, been a long day! Thank you :)